# Gradually Slowing Down 2D Objects Approach

Tags: javascript, html, animation, 2d

I am thinking of any good and verified algorithm for gradually slowing down object approach on a website.

On my website, I wish to introduce new objects, and they should come from the outside of the screen to their desired position. However, I do not wish them to come in constant speed, but I wish them to gradually slow down, until they finally stop at the desired position.

This should add softer feeling from the webpage.

Is there any good algorithm available, that will work well, regardless the distance between the original and destination points of the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as "easing", and most animation frameworks have support for it. If you can use something like ExtJS, or jQuery, you'll get easing support for free for your animations. If you are doing things manually, then adding in easing is not that difficult.

I was pretty fond of [these easing implementations](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/), which are written in ActionScript but trivially ported to JavaScript. I incorporated them into my game engine with great success. And here is a good [demo page](http://hosted.zeh.com.br/mctween/animationtypes.html) showing the same easing functions in action.

Comment: +1 - Hi Matt,thanks for the answer. It is to the point. At this moment, I use no external libraries, and I do not wish to just to have "easing" incorporated. Therefore, I hope, someone will be able to come with a good algorithm. Anyway, the word **"easing"** is new to me, and I think, it will be easier to find relevant lings on google now.

Comment: "easing" is the algorithm. Well, the class of algorithms. The specific names are things like `ease in cubic`, or `ease out quadratic`. You give them a starting value, an ending value, your current time and it will spit out what the current position should be. Try the demo page that I linked to.

Comment: The demo page is very good including v various easing algorithms. Excellent examples, and now I see, I have many more possibilities to chose from. I will search google on specific easing type name. Thanks Matt.

Comment: For all who are interested, this [web page](http://gizma.com/easing/) **contains all the specific easing algorithms**. It is the resource I was looking for.